# How can I download multiple scripts in the resolve section with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs

I recently had a question on how I could load jQuery when I moved to a new page
using AngularJS ui-router. Here's the answer that I accepted:

```
 resolve:{
    jquery: function($q){
      if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        var wait = setInterval(function(){
          if (typeof jQuery === 'function') {
            console.log('jQuery:', typeof jQuery)
            deferred.resolve();
            clearInterval(wait);
          }
        }, 100);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
   }
  }
```

Can someone tell me how I can extend this so I get the jQuery script and also another
local script from my server. The important thing for me is that the second script would need to download after jQuery as it depends on it.

The second script I need to get is /Scripts/pagedown/markdown.js

Please note I am not looking for a solution that uses an external library like require.js. I have only one time I am doing this so using an external library would be overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the script loading process into a more generic, standalone function meant for reuse:

```
var injectJs = function(url, name, deferred) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    var wait = setInterval(function(){
        if (typeof window[name] === 'function') {
            deferred.resolve();
            clearInterval(wait);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Create another promise for markdown.js:

```
var mdDeferred = $q.defer();
```

Then, instead of returning the jQuery loading promise from the function, add a callback to it:

```
jqDeferred.promise.then(function(){
```

... and inside of that callback, use `injectJS` again to load the markdown promise, resolving its promise once it has.

**Note**: you need to pass the name (a string) of the object to check for in as the third object. For jQuery, it is 'jQuery'. Find out what object will be found on the window object once the script loads and use that.

Finally, it's the markdown promise that should now be returned from the resolve function:

```
return mdDeferred.promise;
```

Review this [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gtAjD0hwFkgIwOlAIM1B?p=preview) to see a working example, which uses Underscore in place of markdown.js.

Comment: Thank you for your very professional answer and sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://requirejs.org/ since it's the best solution here.

**jquery-deps.js:**

```
define(['jquery-min'], function (dep1) {
 // Your local script here. Dependent file will be fetched here if needed
 return someObject;  //For example, jQuery object
});
```

**You can add this in router resove:**

```
require(['jquery-min'], function(dependency) {
  // jquery will be fetched first, then more scripts will be executed.
  // Add more scripts
});
```

Take a look at requireJS docs, it's easy to implement and don't include js files using plain javascript just because it's not safe and not cool enough.

Comment: Thanks but I have only the one time I need to do this in my application so require.js is very much overkill. I'm sorry I should have mentioned this in the question.